# Como corrigir erro ORA - dia da semana inválido?

Tags: oracle

Quando executo a consulta direto no Oracle retorna correto, mas quando faço via InteliJ/java, retorna o erro: ORA-01846: não é um dia da semana válido.

```
 SELECT analog,DEVTYP, trunc(data), Max(dis)dis
  FROM table a, table b
  WHERE a.table_index = b.table_index
      AND 
      b.substn = 'valor1'
      AND b.DEVTYP = 'valor2'
      and
      b.analog = 'valor3'
      AND   
   -- CONDITION FOR LAST THREE FRIDAYS
   TRUNC(data) IN (
        TRUNC(NEXT_DAY(SYSDATE - 8,'WED')),
        TRUNC(NEXT_DAY(SYSDATE - 15,'WED')),
        TRUNC(NEXT_DAY(SYSDATE - 22,'WED'))
    ) 
   -- CONDITION FOR 12 TO 18 HOURS
   AND data - TRUNC(data) BETWEEN 12/24 and 18/24
   GROUP BY trunc(data), analog,DEVTYP
```

Comment: O bom é sempre estar em "ingrés" , tudo em geral funciona , achei este tratado para resolver isto. https://community.oracle.com/thread/4023654?start=15&tstart=0

Comment: TRUNC(NEXT_DAY(SYSDATE - 8,4)),   tb funcionou aqui na minha versão

Comment: Obrigado! Alterei meu código no java para informar "Seg", "Ter", ..... para os dias da semana, e então funcionou.

Answer (score 0):

Solução: utilizar os dias da semana abreviados em português no momento de criar a query no Java. **Se executar direto no banco, funciona com as abreviações em Inglês.

```
 SELECT analog,DEVTYP, trunc(data), Max(dis)dis
  FROM table a, table b
  WHERE a.table_index = b.table_index
      AND 
      b.substn = 'valor1'
      AND b.DEVTYP = 'valor2'
      and
      b.analog = 'valor3'
      AND   
   -- CONDITION FOR LAST THREE FRIDAYS
   TRUNC(data) IN (
        TRUNC(NEXT_DAY(SYSDATE - 8,'Qua')),
        TRUNC(NEXT_DAY(SYSDATE - 15,'Qua')),
        TRUNC(NEXT_DAY(SYSDATE - 22,'Qua'))
    ) 
   -- CONDITION FOR 12 TO 18 HOURS
   AND data - TRUNC(data) BETWEEN 12/24 and 18/24
   GROUP BY trunc(data), analog,DEVTYP
```